# MVC Entity Type Missing

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm brand new to ASP.NET MVC (Literally just two days of learning on the fly). I'm trying to create a website using MVC, however, I've screwed something up in my solution.

I created this table that had foreign key constraints but I initially forgot to set up a primary key on the id field and forgot to set it identity specification to yes.  So when I updated my DataModel and brought this table in, it showed every field as being the primary key and it showed the relationship to the other tables.  So I went back to the database and changed the id field for the table to be the primary key and identity specification to yes.

I went back to the DataModel, tried to Update Model From Database, went to the refresh tab, expanded the tables, and selected the table I wanted to refresh, then click on "Finish".

The data model appeared to make the changes but it showed the relationships to the other tables twice.

So I thought I'd delete the table (entity) from the DataModel diagrahm and bring the table back in through Update Model From Database.  But when I went back to the Update Model From Database...

1. Under the Add tab, the table isn't under the Tables
2. Under the Refresh tab, the table is listed, but when I select it and click on "Finish" the table doesn't reaapear in the diagrahm.

In the model browser... 
Under Models

- Entity Types, The entity isn't listed
- Under Associations, The relationships no longer appear (obviously because the entity is gone).

Under Models.Store

- Tables/Views, The table is listed.
- Constraints, the relationships are shown.

I've tried dragging the table over to the diagrahm from the Model Browser, but that doesn't appear to work.

I've tried to right click in the diagrahm, add Entity but my table doesn't appear as a Base Type.

I've tried to google but I'm coming up with nothing.  With this entity missing, I cannot even build my solution.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the entity file and add it again. But you have to name it as previous entity and don't forget to delete the connectionString in web.config before add it.

If you don't know what I am saying just let me know.

Comment: Absolutely, I follow you, I'll give it a try tomorrow.  I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do that.  That's for your input.

Comment: Debugging something like this is really annoying. Most of the time I do update my entity in your method, but sometimes errors like this happens unexpectedly... ^_^

Comment: Thank you, nofortee.  I was able to delete the model, delete the connectionstring and recreate the model.  No issues, application is back up and running.